# How to use ap_parse_form_data and keep request body?

Tags: c, apache, apache-modules

I am developing a module for apache that performs some authentication before passing requests off to the backend. Some of this authentication at times requires parsing form data. The problem is that `ap_parse_form_data` appears to exhaust the request body, so that by the time it passes my module and gets to the `ProxyPass` directive which funnels it off to the backend, the request body is gone and the backend thinks there is no form data supplied.

Is there any way to use `ap_parse_form_data` in such a way that it keeps the request body intact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, I ended up not figuring out how to get `ap_parse_form_data` to not discard the request body. I was able to achieve the same effect by manually adding back a request body like so:

```c
apr_bucket_brigade *new_brigade = apr_brigade_create(req->pool, req->connection->bucket_alloc);
apr_bucket *bucket = apr_bucket_transient_create(reencoded_form_data,
    strlen(reencoded_form_data), req->connection->bucket_alloc);
APR_BRIGADE_INSERT_TAIL(new_brigade, bucket);    
req->kept_body = new_brigade;
```

This is not ideal since it does not deal with the discarding of the request body side-effect if `ap_parse_form_data` is called on a request body that does not actually contain form data. But it works enough for my purposes...